# .htaccesss two sites

Tags: .htaccess

I have two sites running in the same domain (the same sites, but the old in wordpress and the new custom)

I need to do:

If the client ask for a file that exists, then he can see it: (this works)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Any other request goes to index.php

```
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Ok... but if you ask for / (www.site.com) you will have be redirected to www.site.com/site2  without going trough index.php

how can I achieve this?
in pseudocode (bad english, sorry)

```
if(request == "/" || request == www.site.com) {
    redirect site2/
} else if(ask_for_a_file_that_exists) {
    server file
} else {
    use old index.php
}
```

Comment: Do you want to perform an internal or external redirection? Also, does the new site have its own `mod_rewrite` rules in a `.htaccess` file in the `site2` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
# Check if the request was for the root, and if so, redirect
# internally to the site2 folder
RewriteRule ^$ /site2/ [L]

# Otherwise, let the existing site take care of the rest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```